# Install Kivy Garden Flowers in Pycharm

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm, kivy

How does one install flowers from the kivy garden within PyCharm (2019.1) such as Graph and matplotlib flowers? I already installed the kivy.garden package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On kivy website specifies the new format to install garden flowers. It changed since version 1.11.0

Garden flowers can now be installed with the pip tool like a normal python package. Given a flower that you want to install, lets use graph as an example. You can install master directly from github with:

`python -m pip install https://github.com/kivy-garden/graph/archive/master.zip`

Full instructions on kivy website:

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.garden.html?highlight=install%20garden

Hope this helps